# Tensorflow Gpu Support, check if tf is using my GPU?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

i try to get tensorflows gpu support and installed all required software like cuda...
So now i want to check if my code really uses my gpu, but i'm not really sure what it means (unsure because of "Found device 0 with properties"):

`print(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices())`

Output is:

````
2.3.0
2020-12-11 13:28:30.220505: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2020-12-11 13:28:30.249113: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1716] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 2070 with Max-Q Design computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.185GHz coreCount: 36 deviceMemorySize: 8.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 357.69GiB/s
2020-12-11 13:28:30.249473: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-12-11 13:28:30.253079: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2020-12-11 13:28:30.256500: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2020-12-11 13:28:30.257517: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2020-12-11 13:28:30.261527: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2020-12-11 13:28:30.263554: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2020-12-11 13:28:30.271417: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-12-11 13:28:30.271623: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1858] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU'), PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:XLA_CPU:0', device_type='XLA_CPU'), PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU'), PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:XLA_GPU:0', device_type='XLA_GPU')]```
````

Comment: device 0 is your first GPU. One super easy way to check is to open up task manager or equivalent while you run your code and see if your VRAM is being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you install `pip install tensorflow` or `pip install tensorflow-gpu`?

If is the latter, from the output of `tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices()`, your GPU is using, because the tensorflow can find your GeForce RTX 2070 GPU and successfully open all the library that tensorflow needed to usig GPU, so don't worry about it

Give you a example of my computer which I installed the former, the output is like this:

```
2020-12-11 20:40:16.336824: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll 
not found
2020-12-11 20:40:16.337402: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
2020-12-11 20:40:19.716047: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2020-12-11 20:40:20.813638: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1716] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 2060 computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.2GHz coreCount: 30 deviceMemorySize: 6.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 245.91GiB/s
2020-12-11 20:40:20.814470: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll 
not found
2020-12-11 20:40:20.814951: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'cublas64_10.dll'; dlerror: cublas64_10.dll not found
2020-12-11 20:40:20.815328: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'cufft64_10.dll'; dlerror: cufft64_10.dll not 
found
2020-12-11 20:40:20.816220: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'curand64_10.dll'; dlerror: curand64_10.dll not found
2020-12-11 20:40:20.816770: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'cusolver64_10.dll'; dlerror: cusolver64_10.dll not found
2020-12-11 20:40:20.818276: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'cusparse64_10.dll'; dlerror: cusparse64_10.dll not found
2020-12-11 20:40:20.818777: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'cudnn64_7.dll'; dlerror: cudnn64_7.dll not found
2020-12-11 20:40:20.818963: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1753] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU'), PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:XLA_CPU:0', device_type='XLA_CPU'), PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:XLA_GPU:0', device_type='XLA_GPU')]
```

Check using log:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)

# Create some tensors
a = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])
b = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]])
c = tf.matmul(a, b)

print(c)
```

If it print something like this then it is run in GPU (If is end with CPU:0 then the CPU is been using):

```
Executing op MatMul in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
tf.Tensor(
[[22. 28.]
 [49. 64.]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: thanks, problem is that i need  to use a specific tf version. so i'm not using tf-gpu but just tf. When i run a model.fit() it also says: "Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll". But i'm still not sure if it really uses my gpu

Comment: Works! Thank u so much ! :D

Comment: No problem! : )